# How to import NumPy to AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, aws-lambda, python-import

I'm facing the NumPy 1.25.1 import error on AWS Lambda then i try to run it.

I uploaded code from .zip file through AWS Web client.

Here is the **requirements** i used to create a layer:

```
charset-normalizer==3.2.0
contourpy==1.1.0
cycler==0.11.0
docopt==0.6.2
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
fonttools==4.41.0
idna==3.4
kiwisolver==1.4.4
numpy==1.25.1
packaging==23.1
Pillow==10.0.0
psutil==5.9.5
pyparsing==3.0.9
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2023.3
simpy==4.0.1
six==1.16.0
tzdata==2023.3
XlsxWriter==3.1.2
openpyxl==3.1.2
requests==2.31.0
```

Lambda's and layer's Runtimes are equal: `Python 3.11`

Error message:

```bash
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.11 from "/var/lang/bin/python3.11"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.25.1"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

Traceback (most recent call last):
```

*I know there is already exists the same questions, but i've not seen with the same as mine Runtime and NumPy versions. So maybe the solving will be different*

I tried to:

- change the NumPy version to 1.25.2 [same problem]
- change Runtime version to Python 3.10/3.9/3.8 [urllib import error]

Comment: Have you made sure everything is compatible, version-wise, in terms of the OS, the Python version, the Numpy version, etc? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html

Comment: Yes, Lambda supports Python 3.11 and NumPy version is also supported by Python 3.11. Actually i can run this code on my laptop and it works fine.

Comment: I'd make sure the OS is okay as well as the virtual environment. You can test a similar setup by SSHing into an Amazon EC2 instance and seeing if you can get it working there.

Comment: @RandomDavis is there any guide how to do this?

Comment: Probably, but you'll have to research that on your own, or hope someone else knows of a specific one; I'd have to search Google for one, just like you.

Answer (score 1):

The AWS managed [Data-Wrangler Layer](https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/2.15.0/layers.html) for Python Lambda functions includes NumPy. Including it in your Lambda function is as simple as picking it from the dropdown of managed layers.

Comment: I see versions for Python 3.9 highest. Can it work with Python 3.11 Runtime or not? I'm asking because on the lower versions of Python i'm facing import problems with urllib.

Comment: Sorry, they renamed it "The AWS SDK for Pandas". The are much newer versions, including Python 3.11 versions, https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-pandas/releases/tag/3.4.0